# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

I tried to run `pip install spatial-correlation-sampler` in mac terminal but got the error -

> Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Full error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/cw/7_q449q1001fzq0ttwsy_qd80000gn/T/pip-install-puv5x7oh/spatial-correlation-sampler/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/cw/7_q449q1001fzq0ttwsy_qd80000gn/T/pip-install-puv5x7oh/spatial-correlation-sampler/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/cw/7_q449q1001fzq0ttwsy_qd80000gn/T/pip-install-puv5x7oh/spatial-correlation-sampler/
    Complete output (13 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/cw/7_q449q1001fzq0ttwsy_qd80000gn/T/pip-install-puv5x7oh/spatial-correlation-sampler/setup.py", line 57, in <module>
        launch_setup()
      File "/private/var/folders/cw/7_q449q1001fzq0ttwsy_qd80000gn/T/pip-install-puv5x7oh/spatial-correlation-sampler/setup.py", line 40, in launch_setup
        extra_link_args=['-lgomp'])
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 476, in CUDAExtension
        library_dirs += library_paths(cuda=True)
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 555, in library_paths
        if (not os.path.exists(_join_cuda_home(lib_dir)) and
      File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1146, in _join_cuda_home
        raise EnvironmentError('CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. '
    OSError: CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. Please set it to your CUDA install root.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Could you fix this problem? how?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment due to reputation, but do you have CUDA installed? What happens when you run

```
nvcc --version
```

in command line?

Comment: I have the same issue when running `pip install MySQL-python` . I don't have `CUDA installed..

Comment: Hi, egg_info is a structure used by setup tools that details information about a software package.  Usually egg_info errors mean that you have problems with or are missing dependencies.  In your case, have you installed MySQL?.  Make sure that it is working correctly.  If so, try it in a virtual environment to avoid any conflicting packages.