# Unable to install the new tflite-support using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, package, tensorflow2.0

Following this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata), I've been trying to install the `tflite-support` module using pip. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gg/1zr67t6d11lczcdmc7tc3y000000gn/T/pip-install-tfso4suc/tflite-support/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gg/1zr67t6d11lczcdmc7tc3y000000gn/T/pip-install-tfso4suc/tflite-support/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/gg/1zr67t6d11lczcdmc7tc3y000000gn/T/pip-install-tfso4suc/tflite-support/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /private/var/folders/gg/1zr67t6d11lczcdmc7tc3y000000gn/T/pip-install-tfso4suc/tflite-support/
Complete output (27 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/gg/1zr67t6d11lczcdmc7tc3y000000gn/T/pip-install-tfso4suc/tflite-support/setup.py", line 178, in <module>
    zip_safe=False,
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 143, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 138, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 698, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 783, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 754, in fetch_build_egg
    return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 133, in fetch_build_egg
    wheel.install_as_egg(dist_location)
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 103, in install_as_egg
    self._install_as_egg(destination_eggdir, zf)
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 111, in _install_as_egg
    self._convert_metadata(zf, destination_eggdir, dist_info, egg_info)
  File "/Users/anupamchugh/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 132, in _convert_metadata
    os.mkdir(destination_eggdir)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/private/var/folders/gg/1zr67t6d11lczcdmc7tc3y000000gn/T/pip-install-tfso4suc/tflite-support/.eggs/pybind11-2.4.3-py3.7.egg'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any leads? I know similar questions have been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732467/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-the-logs), but no luck with those answers

Comment: This looks like a bug in `setuptools` to me - what version do you have installed? Check e.g. via `python -c "from setuptools.version import __version__ as v; print(v)"`. If it is a 42 or newer, try downgrading to 41.6: `pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<42'`, then reinstall `tflite-support`.

Comment: Also, looking at `tflite-support`'s setup script, it may be wise to preinstall `pybind11` before the actual installation. Once you have downgraded `setuptools`, install `pybind11`: `pip install 'pybind11>=2.4'`, then `pip install tflite-support`.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! You can post this as an answer on the thread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer:

This looks like a regression in `setuptools`. Downgrade to 41:

```
$ pip install --upgrade 'setuptools<42'
```

Now (ideally) preinstall `pybind11` to avoid missing headers when building the `tflite-support` wheel:

```
$ pip install 'pybind11>=2.4'
```

Now installing `tflite-support` should succeed without any intermediate errors:

```
$ pip install tflite-support
```

Comment: First command gives me error: `The system cannot find the file specified.` when I run from Anaconda Prompt